# data viewing in R language

Tags: r

I am probably an idiot, but I cannot find in the docs how to display objects.
A package I installed returns an object called a.

How can I figure out what is in it? There are some matrices and numbers inside this
object that I need.

(I admit a year ago (last time I had to use R) I had the same problem, and I found a solution
after googling for an hour. This time I lost patience after 20 minutes and I hope someone takes pity on me.)

Answer (score 8):

You could type

```
a
```

Or

```
str(a)
```

Or

```
summary(a)
```

Those are good starts

Comment: summary() looks useful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The `str()` function is good at disclosing the general structure of an object. You may need to learn how some of the types of objects get displayed. A matrix will not say "matrix' but with rather be displayed with name[rows, cols]

```
> str(matrix(NA, 4,4) )
 logi [1:4, 1:4] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

There are various versions of a `describe` function that are improvements for dataframes over the built-in `summary` functions. Then there are functions that can be used to determine `length`, `class`, `mode`, and other features.

Comment: Thanks. I found that the names() function did the trick. Beautiful language! Not! I guess I improved my search time to 30 minutes though!

Comment: It would have helped if you had mentioned that you were dealing with a list, i.e. first used the `class` function. `names` is not going not work on a matrix. It will work on some atomic vectors, but not all. `str` would work on most classes.

Comment: Thanks DWin, indeed. I did not know about class() either... I read the (109 page) "An Introduction to R" and it does not have an example featuring the class() function. It does mention the unclass() function though, so I guess I could have figured it out. Maybe this is also related: "A special attribute known as the class of the object is used to allow for an object-oriented..." (page 21).

Comment: I did not find an example to dispute the lack of an example.... but... The paragraph preceding the example you cite does say that classes are "reported by the function `class`". And you must admit that if you go through that 109 page document with a search engine, that references to the class of objects occur throughout. And Section 10.9 focuses on classes.

Answer (score 3):

The real solution is to read the package documentation. For example, to get the fitted values out of a GLM, you do `fitted(a)`. To get the nearest neighbour distances with `splancs:nndistG` you get `a$dists`.

If the return value of a function in a package isn't documented, tell the maintainer. This is a bug.

If you go digging around in the structure of an object, thinking that `a$foo` is what you want with no documentation, then there's a chance you won't be getting what you think you are getting. For example suppose a model fitting function has a `$resid` component. You don't know what kind of residuals these are.

Also, there's no guarantee that an upgrade of the package will keep the same definition of `$resid`, and the change might not be documented because the author wasn't expecting people to dig around in the guts of the objects.